# Domain configuration after upgrading to Windows 8 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

Will Windows 8 keep my current domain and user profile configuration after upgrading? Do I have an option not to opt into the same domain and still bring my current profile over?

Comment: Duplicate? Seems similar to other questions.

Comment: Can you link me to the question? I'll happily delete this one.